# Structuring main JS site file using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, structure, es6-modules

I'm trying to convert over to using ES6. Currently I"m using gulp to handle everything and Ive got babel transpiring my ES6 just fine. I've converted what was a require into imports and everything works.

I just can't work out how is best to structure my main JS file that ties everything together.

In the past I've had a Site function auto invoking that has globals, a module object and an init function that loops through all the functions placed inside a 'module's object and runs them.

I then had a second auto invoked function that i used to inject functions into the module object via a passed reference, and I'd also pass the globals over at this point.

However this seems wrong when using ES6 imports. I just can't find an example of how to tie together modules to actually build the site without having an absolute mess of a JS file.

I have considered converting the Site function to a class to retain the ability for functions inside to call each other. Though this is not ideal. I have also been looking into separating all the individual functionality components into individual models but i again need a way to initialise these modules and I"m bak to square one.

does anyone have examples of how to structure a JS site file that makes use of modules in a way that is easily readable and clean?

I'd love to be able to have a folder structure like the following

```
js
├── modules/
│   ├── initialisaiton.js
│   ├── banner.js
│   ├── testimonials.js
│   └── navigation.js
├── utils.js
└── mian.js
```

Being able to separate out every chunk of individual functionality into its own file. I know how to work this way, but I ideally don't want to have to have a massive list of imports in my main.js file and I need to be able to cross over modules with say navigation calling functions in other modules.

I've spent a long time looking up tutorials and guides and looking at other SO questions, but these always seem to be about basic examples of ES6 functionality, or how to make a module. Now on structures for tying everything together. S if anyone has some advice, examples or code samples that would be a great hep.

**Edit: here is what I currently have converted to an ES6 class**

```
import * as utils from './utils';

const moduleRegistration = function(m, u, ui, win, doc){

    // Example Module
    m.example = function(){
        // Do stuff, the m.example module gets auto initialized.
    };

    // Document loaded class
    m.docLoad = function(){
        u.addClass(doc.body, 'is-loaded');
    };

};

class Site {

    constructor() {
        // DOM caching
        this.win = window;
        this.doc = document;

        this.doc.documentElement.setAttribute('data-ua',  navigator.userAgent);

        // Globals
        this.ui = {
            fast: 0.2,
            slow: 0.4,
            step: 0.03
        };
        this.modules = {};

        this.init();
    }

    init(){
        moduleRegistration(this.modules, utils, this.ui, this.win, this.doc);

        for (const prop in this.modules) {
            if ( this.modules.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
                this.modules[prop]();
            }
        }
    }

}

utils.documentReady(()=>{ new Site(); });
```

**Edit: And the original**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Site.init();
});

var Site = (function($) {

    // DOM caching
    var win = window;

    // Globals
    var w = {
        width:  win.innerWidth,
        height: win.innerHeight,
        scroll: win.pageYOffset
    };

    var ui = {
        fast: 0.2,
        slow: 0.4,
        step: 0.03
    };

    function updateGlobals(){
        w.width  = win.innerWidth;
        w.height = win.innerHeight;
        w.scroll = win.pageYOffset;
    }

    win.addEventListener('resize', updateGlobals, true);
    win.addEventListener('scroll', updateGlobals, true);
    win.addEventListener('load', updateGlobals, true);

    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-ua',  navigator.userAgent);

    return {
        autoInits: require('./auto'),
        init: function(){

            for (var prop in this.modules) {
                if ( this.modules.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
                    this.modules[prop]();
                }
            }

            for (var props in this.autoInits) {
                if ( this.autoInits.hasOwnProperty(props) ) {
                    var $selector = $(props);

                    if ($selector.length) {
                        this.autoInits[props]($selector);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        utils: require('./utils'),
        ui: ui,
        w: w
    };

})(jQuery);

(function(m, u, ui, w, a, $){

    var menu_state = false;

    // Example Module
    m.example = function(){
        // Do stuff, the m.example module gets auto initialized.
    };

    // Document loaded class
    m.docLoad = function(){
        u.addClass(document.body, 'is-loaded');
    };

})(Site.modules = Site.modules || {}, Site.utils, Site.ui, Site.w, Site.anim, jQuery);
```

Comment: Using `import` instead of `require` shouldn't change anything. Can you please post your (simplified) code (showing only what should be called in what order and how functions depend on each other)

Comment: @Bergi I've added my current js converted to an ES6 class

Comment: As you noticed, it's not ideal to use a `class` here, there's absolutely no reason to do that conversion. Can you please post your original code?

Comment: @Bergi Edited question